# JPanel layout manager

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, layout-manager

I need to make such table in a `JPanel`.

Any ideas how to do it, to get the layout like the one on the picture below?

[image: here]

Comment: See the tutorial [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jtable/info) and post a [mcve] that shows what you tried.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer can more easily be found by reading a suitable tutorial, like [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple code for creating a JTable like that

```
detailsTable = new JTable();
    detailsTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    detailsTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {},
            new String[] { "LAST_NAME", "FIRST_NAME"}));

scrollPane = new JScrollPane(detailsTable);
panel1.add(scrollPane);
```

If you want to add to a table, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24932977/displaying-the-values-of-an-arraylist-with-a-jtable)

Hope this Helps!!!

Comment: You don't have to use setBounds, I use it because it makes designing my Panels easier with absolute layout

Comment: Absolute layouts might seem "easier", but in the long run, you'd be better off learning how to make use of the layout management API. Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: what layout does the panel1 have?

Comment: @OliverWatkins By default, `JPanel` uses `FlowLayout`, you may want to use a `BorderLayout`